# BinaryFormatter устарел, что делать?

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация

Начиная с .NET 5 BinaryFormatter объявлен [устаревшим](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) из-за небезопасности.

Рекомендуемый путь - переключение на protobuf, вот здесь есть [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799591/is-there-a-high-performance-way-to-replace-the-binaryformatter-in-net5).

Что непонятно: как переписать сериализацию и десериализацию так, чтобы была совместимость со старыми файлами, созданными с помощью BinaryFormatter?

Comment: _чтобы была совместимость_ - это невозможно. Нужно перейти на какой-нибудь новый формат, перегнав все старые данные в него.

Comment: А зачем вам BinaryFormatter? Назначение какое? Что им сериализуете? Куда отправляете, откуда принимаете?

Comment: Есть программа с незапамятных времен, сейчас делаю ей апгрейд на .NET 6. BinaryFormatter используется для сериализации и десериализации внутренних данных в файл.

Comment: Видимо, пока просто включу EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization, а в случае чего уже сделаю конвертер старого формата во что-то типа JSON

Comment: А зачем .NET 5? Если есть LTS версия дотнета .NET 6? Более шустрая и стабильная. В частности в .NET 6 сильно переработана асинхронная работа с файлами, внутрянка. А BinaryFormatter вы можете хоть вечно использовать, его вынесут в NuGet пакет. А protobuf не нужен, если не используете gRPC.

Comment: [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md)

Comment: @aepot Так я делаю до .NET 6. Пока продолжаю использовать BinaryFormatter, но есть инфа, что из седьмой версии его окончательно выкинут.

Comment: Выкинут его из 9 версии, я же ссылку дал. Не нужен .NET 5, он уже устаревает, мигрируйте сразу на 6.

Comment: BF нельзя использовать для связи с внешним миром. Потому что мамкин хакер может гадость прислать. А для внутреннего использования он вполне годится. Вы же сами себе не будете неверные данные подсовывать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для внутреннего использования сериализация как правило не нужна. А то что у автора кластер и он использует всякие AMQP - не похоже, а там бы мог пригодиться тот же protobuf.

Comment: Это для внутреннего потребления. Как бы свой собственный формат файлов. Обмена по сети и чего-то такого нет, поэтому вряд ли злобный хакер похитит эти данные.

Comment: Не `CookieContainer` ли вы так сохраняете случаем?

Comment: @aepot Нет, CookieContainer не причем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ по итогу обсуждения в комментариях:

1. Лучше отказаться от `BinaryFormatter` и перейти на другой метод сериализации и десериализации, более новый/безопасный.
2. При переходе на новый формат совместимости со старыми данными не будет.
3. Если все же нужно сохранить `BinaryFormatter` (и данные никуда не передаются/какой-то внутренний формат, т.е. особых требований по безопасности нет), то в файл проекта нужно включить:

```
<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
```